# Unity C# Error, DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following an Inventory tutorial series and it is using JSON to save the data used for the inventory.

The error is in this block

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using LitJson;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;


public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
private List<Item> database = new List<Item>();
private JsonData itemData;

void Start()
{

    itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Items.json"));
    ConstructItemDatabase();

    Debug.Log(database[1].Player);

}
```

The error I am getting is

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "H:\Webb_Finale\Fantasy\Assets\StreamingAssets\Items.json".
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:292)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:363)
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:167)
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string,System.Text.Encoding)
>   System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:587)
>   System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:582)
>   ItemDatabase.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/ItemDatabase.cs:13

I am not sure what to do to fix this problem, thanks for any help!

Comment: Does "H:\Webb_Finale\Fantasy\Assets\StreamingAssets\" actually exist?

Comment: Yes http://imgur.com/LpvKBsf

Comment: Alright, one more possibility: what's your target platform in build settings right now?

Comment: My build setting in unity are set to Windows. Architecture x86_64